# Fastest way to convert RTF to FlowDocument

Tags: wpf, flowdocument

What is the fastest way to convert a RTF to FlowDocument? I store RTF as plain string and then reload it back, I am using following method,

```
FlowDocument document = new FlowDocument();
document.SetValue(FlowDocument.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Left);

TextRange content = new TextRange(document.ContentStart, document.ContentEnd);

if (content.CanLoad(DataFormats.Rtf) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(rtf) == false)
{
     // If so then load it with RTF
     byte[] valueArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rtf);
     using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(valueArray))
     {
         content.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
     }
}
```

But this method is very slow. I need to load many RTFs (around 1000). What can be the trick to make the process fast? Is there any other way around to load a Flowdocument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to define what you actually need. TextBlock is not weak at all.
It has things to offer ;).

- Colours(Background/Foreground + you can color specific part of TextBlock even)
- Alignments(you can align TextBlocks as you want, and perhaps even part of them?! Not sure about the last one.
- It has TextDecorations, which means it supports bold/italic/underline/strikethrough etc.
- Fonts(yeah it supports custom fonts and whatever font you want)

But fair enough. I think you should store FlowDocument XAML instead of actual RTF. This way there will be no conversion and it should be multiple times faster. (See DataFormats.xaml)

Comment: ChrisDD, Thanks for taking interest, I need functionality like RichTextBox, so I definitely need FlowDocument, problem is how to optimize it while loading many of them (around 1000). Again I need RTF to be stored for some interoperability issues.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Vibhore the TextBlock element should be used when limited text support is required, Label can be used when minimal text support is required.

The FlowDocument element is a container for re-flowable documents that support rich presentation of content, and therefore, has a greater performance impact than using the TextBlock or Label controls.

Comment: Candie, Thanks for replying. I need FlowDocument because I need a lot formatting like Texalignment, TextDecoration, Font, Colors etc, To have such rich formatting I believe FlowDocument is my option, or is there any other way around? Also I am not just displaying text in some TextBlock, I need to create some UI elements each with its own FlowDocument, That's why I have to load multiple FlowDocuments quickly.